# PM2.js to Run Gunicorn/Flask App inside Virtualenv/Anaconda env

Tags: python, flask, conda, gunicorn, pm2

I have been running [gunicorn](https://gunicorn.org/) to serve a Python Flask app using the commands

```
conda activate fooenv
gunicorn --workers=4 -b 0.0.0.0:5000 --worker-class=meinheld.gmeinheld.MeinheldWorker api.app:app
```

How can we use [`pm2`](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/) instead to run gunicorn/flask app inside the `fooenv` environment?

Answer (score 2):

supposed you can run gunicorn in your venv via e.g.:

```
gunicorn wsgi:app -b localhost:5010
```

then you simply use command (in the venv):

```
pm2 --name=myapp start "gunicorn wsgi:app -b localhost:5010"
```

(took me way too long to figure this out btw)

Answer (score 2):

I would create a `pm2.json` file in the same directory as your app, then start it with `pm2 start pm2.json`.  `pm2 ls` will now show your app running.

```json
{
    "apps": [
      {
        "name": "my-app",
        "script": "gunicorn --workers=4 -b 0.0.0.0:5000 --worker-class=meinheld.gmeinheld.MeinheldWorker api.app:app",
        "watch": false,
        "max_memory_restart": "256M",
        "output": "/var/www/html/logs/my-app-out.log",
        "error": "/var/www/html/logs/my-app-error.log",
        "kill_timeout": 5000,
        "restartDelay": 5000
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using virtualenv and getting the following error on `pm2 ls`:

```
/usr/bin/bash: line 1: gunicorn: command not found
```

Then, you could try initiating the virtualenv as well in the start command:

```
 pm2 --name=ai start "cd ~/my-python-project-dir && source venv/bin/activate && gunicorn wsgi:app -b localhost:5010"
```